# Duplicate page from Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: url, seo, google-search-console

All of my website page URL contains non-English characters for SEO purpose, but in some browsers, this characters encode and not looks good.

For this reason, I wrote a JavaScript code, for when user click on a link, non-English characters removed and add `canonical` link tag to head of page to say Google use this link for main addressing.

Change this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/game/new/جدید
```

to this, when user click:

```
http://www.example.com/game/new
```

and add this `canonical` link tag in head of two page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/game/new/جدید" />
```

but now after two month and 300 index from Google, In "HTML Improvements" of Google Webmaster Tools, write "Duplicate title tags" for this pages.

I can't remove non-English character from URL or redirect pages.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to think about your URL rewriting in general: if you have configured your website to serve ugly URLs

> for SEO purpose

only, you might think about it and remove them anyway. If you need the non-English characters as they may help your visitors to understand your URLs, keep them. If you don't need them, drop them.

To solve your problem you can try the following:

**First** make sure you know about the URLs by downloading them from Search Console:
simply hit "Download this table" above your URL table.

**Next**, make sure you can always identify a pair of URLs like in your example
`http://www.example.com/game/new/جدید` and `http://www.example.com/game/new`

On `http://www.example.com/game/new/جدید`
implement a canonical link element like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/game/new/جدید">
```

On `http://www.example.com/game/new`
do the same:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/game/new/جدید">
```

Make sure links on your pages always point to the canonical URLs instead of the English-only ones. In sitemaps use the canonical URLs only as well.

Remember: it takes some time for Google to recognize your canonicalization and correct the errors in Search Console.

It has shown as a best practise to implement a self referential canonical link element on each page by default. This protects you from generating duplicates with Parameters or capitalization issues.

**Third:**
Make sure you don't supply further duplicates for example by serving URLs with and without trailing slashes or serving both `http` and `https`. These are the most common duplicate issues. Your problem may also have different reasons. Further, do not implement canonical links dynamically via JavaScript or similar.

If the duplicate Title issues do not resolve you may have further issues either making Google ignore your canonicals or serving duplicate URLs.

Comment: thanks,yes I think Google not recognize canonicalization yet!

Answer (score 1):

Try to export your .htaccess file and rewrite it in a scripting program and fix all the non-english characters away, then import it back to your cPanel

Comment: thanks for answering, I don't remember write,I'm using asp.net.